# Sort XMLs by node innertext or attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following test XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <!--This file is generated by the program.-->
 <Deals>
  <Deal ID="1">
   <Preisformular>
     <Preisbindung>a</Preisbindung>
     <Factor>5</Factor>
     <Date>1-1-2014</Date>
    </Preisformular>
   </Deal>
  <Deal ID="2">
   <Preisformular>
      <Preisbindung>b</Preisbindung>
      <Factor>10</Factor>
      <Date>30-12-2013</Date>
    </Preisformular>
   </Deal>
 </Deals>
```

What i want to do is to sort this XML e.g by Preisbindung. I used this

```
  XElement root = XElement.Load("test.xml")
  var ordered = root.Elements("Deal").Elements("Preisformular")
                              .OrderByDescending(x => (string)x.Element("Preisbindung"))
                              .ToArray();

   root.RemoveAll();
   foreach (XElement tab in ordered)
            root.Add(tab);
   root.Save("test.xml");
```

but the result that i take to the updated XML file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 -<Deals>
   -<Preisformular>
      <Preisbindung>b</Preisbindung>
      <Factor>10</Factor>
      <Date>30-12-2013</Date>
     </Preisformular>
   -<Preisformular>
      <Preisbindung>a</Preisbindung>
      <Factor>5</Factor>
      <Date>1-1-2014</Date>
    </Preisformular>
  </Deals>
```

I know that the problem comes from .RemoveAll(); . Any Idea of how can i keep the original structure but with sorted elements (or attributes)?

**EDITED**

My Expected output is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Deals>
  <Deal ID="2">
   <Preisformular>
      <Preisbindung>b</Preisbindung>
      <Factor>10</Factor>
      <Date>30-12-2013</Date>
     </Preisformular>
   </Deal>
  <Deal ID="1">
   <Preisformular>
      <Preisbindung>a</Preisbindung>
      <Factor>5</Factor>
      <Date>1-1-2014</Date>
    </Preisformular>
   </Deal>
  </Deals>
```

Comment: Is it so hard to post a valid xml? I don't like to fix the codes/xmls/jsons  ..... in the question. My time is as valuable as yours. (BTW: What is your expected output?)

Comment: The XML is valid and produced by a database

Comment: No those `-` s don't belong to your xml. Most probably you use IE explorer to view your xml.

Comment: Invalid xml + unclear what is asked => vote to close.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Valid XML means I could copy and paste it into an XML document and have it be valid. Those "-" signs make your XML not valid.

Comment: Good catch @JohnSaunders. the only wrong point in this question was the title.

Comment: @L.B: the title, and the invalid XML, and using the word "XMLs" instead of "XML documents", ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XElement dealsParent = doc.Element("Deals");
dealsParent.ReplaceNodes(dealsParent.Nodes().Cast<XElement>().OrderByDescending(element => element.Element("Preisformular").Element("Preisbindung").Value));
```

Result:

```
<Deals>
  <Deal ID="2">
    <Preisformular>
      <Preisbindung>b</Preisbindung>
      <Factor>10</Factor>
      <Date>30-12-2013</Date>
    </Preisformular>
  </Deal>
  <Deal ID="1">
    <Preisformular>
      <Preisbindung>a</Preisbindung>
      <Factor>5</Factor>
      <Date>1-1-2014</Date>
    </Preisformular>
  </Deal>
</Deals>
```

**EDIT** (Complete LINQPad C# Program that gives the above result):

```
void Main()
{
    string xml =
@"<Deals>
<Deal ID=""1"">
    <Preisformular>
    <Preisbindung>a</Preisbindung>
    <Factor>5</Factor>
    <Date>1-1-2014</Date>
    </Preisformular>
    </Deal>
<Deal ID=""2"">
    <Preisformular>
        <Preisbindung>b</Preisbindung>
        <Factor>10</Factor>
        <Date>30-12-2013</Date>
    </Preisformular>
    </Deal>
</Deals>";

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    XElement dealsParent = doc.Element("Deals");
    dealsParent.ReplaceNodes(dealsParent.Nodes().Cast<XElement>().OrderByDescending(element => element.Element("Preisformular").Element("Preisbindung").Value));

    dealsParent.Dump();
}
```

Comment: in my case your proposal gives the initial XML

Comment: I updated the code I posted with `OrderByDescending` after you clarified your expected output.  Did you get the updated code?

Comment: Have you used LINQPad before?  I'm updating my post with a complete LINQPad C# program that gives me the expected result.

Comment: Which collection do you use for this? (i mean for .Dump)

Comment: Ahh... Did you replace your code completely?  My code doesn't do a save.  Make sure you still do a `doc.Save("test.xml");`

Comment: `.Dump()` is a LINQPad extension method that just shows the results in the result pane.  See my comment about making sure you didn't replace your saving of the XML file.

Comment: Save was missing. you are correct and +1